# Enable capabilities for Unity3D xCode Project in postprocess

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, post-processing

I have a Unity3D iOS project, where I use Game Center and In-App Purchases(via third-party plugins), but when I build Unity3D project into xCode, in the Capabilities section Game Center and In-App Purchases are disabled. I need to enable them in a PostProcessBuild method. I tried using xCodeApi via this code:

```
   string projPath = PBXProject.GetPBXProjectPath(pathToBuiltProject);
   PBXProject proj = new PBXProject();

   proj.ReadFromString(File.ReadAllText(projPath));
   string target = proj.TargetGuidByName("Unity-iPhone");

   proj.AddCapability (target, PBXCapabilityType.GameCenter);
   proj.AddCapability (target, PBXCapabilityType.InAppPurchase);

   File.WriteAllText(projPath, proj.ToString());
```

But after this xCode is unable to open the created project(it just crashes immidietly). How do I add these two capabilities without setting them manually in xCode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem was with invalid projPath and that I did not enable iCloud. This code works:

```
[PostProcessBuild(999)]
public static void AddCapabilities(BuildTarget buildTarget, string pathToBuiltProject)
 {
  if (buildTarget == BuildTarget.iOS) {
   string projPath = pathToBuiltProject + "/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj";

   PBXProject proj = new PBXProject ();
   proj.ReadFromString (File.ReadAllText (projPath));

   string target = proj.TargetGuidByName ("Unity-iPhone");

   proj.AddCapability (target, PBXCapabilityType.iCloud);
   proj.AddCapability (target, PBXCapabilityType.GameCenter);
   proj.AddCapability (target, PBXCapabilityType.InAppPurchase);

   File.WriteAllText (projPath, proj.WriteToString ());

  }
}
```

For now I am having trouble only with setting iCloud flags key-value storage and CloudKit to true. As far as I've read, it needs some entitlement file, which I do not know where to find. If you know how to help, I would appreciate some comments.

Comment: Using "Unity-iPhone" is deprecated now. This answer is no longer true.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a new way that this is achievable:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Build;
using UnityEditor.Build.Reporting;
using UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode;

public class CapabilityPostprocessBuild : IPostprocessBuildWithReport
{
    public int callbackOrder => 999;

    public void OnPostprocessBuild(BuildReport report)
    {
        OnPostprocessBuild(report.summary.platform, report.summary.outputPath);
    }

    public void OnPostprocessBuild(BuildTarget buildTarget, string path)
    {
        if (buildTarget == BuildTarget.iOS)
        {
            string projPath = PBXProject.GetPBXProjectPath(path);

            PBXProject proj = new PBXProject();
            proj.ReadFromFile(projPath);

            ProjectCapabilityManager manager = new ProjectCapabilityManager(
                projPath,
                "Entitlements.entitlements",
                targetGuid: proj.GetUnityMainTargetGuid()
            );

            manager.AddiCloud(true, false, null);

            manager.WriteToFile();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for me. After adding this, I can clearly see that iCloud is added in my xcode project and tested on the actual device works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: when i added ur code , i got : The type or namespace name 'Build' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEditor' (are you missing an assembly reference?) how to fix it ?

Comment: @Noob try placing the script in a folder with the name "Editor".

Answer (score 3):

you can use `ProjectCapabilityManager` to add `iCloud` capability with `key-value` storage flag

```
using XcodeUnityCapability = UnityEditor.iOS.XcodeUnity.ProjectCapabilityManager;
public class IosPostProcessBuild : MonoBehaviour
{
    [PostProcessBuild]
    private static void PostBuildActions(BuildTarget buildTarget, string path)
    {
        if (buildTarget == BuildTarget.iOS)
        {
            string projPath = path + "/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj";
            XcodeUnityCapability projCapability = new XcodeUnityCapability(projPath, "Unity-iPhone/mmk.entitlements", "Unity-iPhone");

            projCapability.AddGameCenter();
            string[] empty = null;
            projCapability.AddiCloud(true, false, empty);
            projCapability.WriteToFile();
        }
    }
}
```

`XcodeUnity` is renamed namespace, you can take xcode api from here https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/xcodeapi/src

Comment: Thanks! `proj.AddCapability` didn't work for me for some reason, but your suggestion worked! FYI : in modern Unity versions, the xcode api is already included in the standard install.

Answer (score 0):

As of 11/21/23, the correctly marked answer here is deprecated. Unity broke their own API as usual. The following will work for Game Center (the GameKit framework) for instance:

```
[PostProcessBuild]
    public static void ProcessForiOS(BuildTarget buildTarget, string path)
    {
        if (buildTarget == BuildTarget.iOS)
        {
            // Add Game Center capability. Required since Unity and Apple ****** everything up with Xcode 15.
            string projectPath = PBXProject.GetPBXProjectPath(path);
            PBXProject project = new PBXProject();
            project.ReadFromString(File.ReadAllText(projectPath));

            string targetGuid = project.GetUnityMainTargetGuid();
            project.AddFrameworkToProject(targetGuid, "GameKit.framework", false);
            File.WriteAllText(projectPath, project.WriteToString());
}
}
```